# Evaluating $\int _{-\pi}^{\pi}x^2cos(nx)dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-series

Hello I'm trying to evaluate $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^2\cos(nx)dx$$

I understand you have to apply integration by parts twice but I always get zero and I know this is wrong.

I always end up with $$-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{2x\sin(nx)}{n} dx$$  which when integrated by parts again just gives me zero. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: show the whole process and detail of your derivations to make commenting possible.

Comment: Instead of using the long version of integration by parts I would use tabular integration it makes keeping track of signs easier

Comment: $I~=~-\displaystyle\frac{d^2}{dn^2}~\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos nx~dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your integration by parts again. You should get $$\int_\ x^2\cos(nx)dx = \frac{x^2\sin(nx)}{n}+\frac{2x\cos(nx)}{n^2}-\frac{2\sin(nx)}{n^3}$$

Comment: After I've applied it once I get $[{x^2sinnx\over n}]$ between -pi and pi which is zero -$\int {2xsinnx \over n}$ dx is that part correct?

Comment: In particular the $\cos$ term should persist while the $\sin$ terms should drop out.

Comment: For this type of integral I use tabular integration. It makes things go very smoothly. But if I did integration by parts the usual way, you should get $$\int x^2 \cos(nx)dx= \frac{x^2\sin(nx)}{n}-\int \frac{2x\sin(nx)}{n} dx$$ after the first iteration, assuming you let $u = x^2$ and $dv = \cos(nx)$

Comment: @rb20 Did you put (solved) in the title to let other users here know that the question has been answered? If so, please mark my answer as the correct one. That is how the website knows that the question is complete.